# Error when start an instance of SQLLOCQLDB 2017 on windows 7 64bit (entry point not found except)

Tags: windows-7-x64, sql-server-express, localdb

I tried to start an instance of SQLLOCALDB 2017 on win7 (x64) but this message box Appears :

> "The procedure entry point BCryptKeyDerivation could not be located in
>   the dynamic link library bcrypt.dll"

Anybody knows it's reason?

[image]

more info from CMD:

> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601] Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft
>   Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Users\hashem-7-x64>SQLLOCALDB INFO MSSQLLocalDB
>
> C:\Users\hashem-7-x64>SQLLOCALDB VERSIONS Microsoft SQL Server 2017
>   (14.0.1000.169)
>
> C:\Users\hashem-7-x64>SQLLOCALDB START MSSQLLOCALDB Start of LocalDB
>   instance "MSSQLLOCALDB" failed because of the following error: Error
>   occurred during LocalDB instance startup: SQL Server process failed to
>   sta rt.
>
> C:\Users\hashem-7-x64>

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and I resolved it by uninstalling Sql Server LocalDB 2017 and installing the 2014 version.

Apparently the 2017 version is not compatible with Windows 7.

Answer (score 6):

SQL Server 2017 Express LocalDB isn't supported on Windows 7. The SqlLocalDB.msi installer for me but when I tried to start an instance it would give the "BCryptKeyDerivation could not be located" error. Anecdotally the 2016 version is supposedly not supported, but it installed and default instances run for me.

Per [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55994) :

> **Supported Operating System**:
>
> Windows 10 , Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012, Windows
>   Server 2012 R2, Windows Server 2016

Some [additional information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448506(v=vs.85).aspx) indicating that you'll need at least Windows 8

> **BCryptKeyDerivation function**
>
> The BCryptKeyDerivation function derives a key without requiring a
>   secret agreement. It is similar in functionality to BCryptDeriveKey
>   but does not require a BCRYPT_SECRET_HANDLE value as input.
>
> **Minimum supported client**
>
> Windows 8 [desktop apps | UWP apps]
>
> **Minimum supported server**
>
> Windows Server 2012 [desktop apps | UWP apps]

Comment: Got the same problem on 2019 too, seems like the 2016 is the last really supported version on Windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

Install [DotNET Core v2 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/visual-studio-sdks) (More specifically [v2.1.4](https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/1/5/115B762D-2B41-4AF3-9A63-92D9680B9409/dotnet-sdk-2.1.4-win-gs-x64.exe) as of now)

The problem is caused by the version of assemblies for cryptographic algorithms currently installed on your PC offered via DotNET:

```
 System.Security.Cryptography
 System.Security.Cryptography.Cng
```

The mentioned update provides the missing  dependencies. Read more about the dependencies on [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Security.Cryptography.Cng/) information page.

Comment: This did not work for me sadly. (win Server 2008 rc2)

Comment: Nor me on Windows 7 Enterprise

Answer (score 0):

Install Sqllocaldb 2016 that work great in windows 7. i facing the same problem last few days and finally i get the answer to install localdb 2016. sqllocaldb 2016 support very well and even we don't need to downgrade the database version.i try sqllocaldb 2014 to but it get me error the database version is not supported. but sqllocaldb 2016 support great [sqllocaldb 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-2016-express-localdb?view=sql-server-2016)